# Serach database not working in php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, search, mysqli, pdo

Please i have been trying to make search in php pdo but is not working when i search it will only show the current title i searched for.
I have been using MYSQL but is showing error at the top of my page but is searching very well like i wanted it to be please can someone convert this Mysql to PDO for me or MYSQLI but i prefer PDO because i understand it more

here is my PHP to get search using mysql

```
<?php require_once("_inc/dbcontroller.php"); $db_handle = new DBController();?>
<?php
         if(isset($_GET['q'])){
        $button = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET ['t']);
        $search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET ['q']); 
        $construct = "";
        if(!$search)
        echo 'The Query String field is required.';
        else{
        if(strlen($search)<=1)
        echo 'The Query String is too short.';
        else{
        echo "You searched for <b>$search</b> <hr size='1'></br>";
        mysql_select_db("your database name");
        $search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

        foreach($search_exploded as $search_each){
        $x =0; $x++;
        if($x==1){$construct .="title LIKE '%$search_each%'";}
        else {
        $construct .="AND blog LIKE '%$search_each%' AND tags LIKE '%$search_each%'";
        }
        }
        $construct ="SELECT * FROM blogtd WHERE $construct AND action = 'active'";
        $run = mysql_query($construct);

        $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);
        if($foundnum==0)
        echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for";
        else{
        echo "We've found match";
        while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){
        $title = $runrows ['title'];
        $body = mysql_real_escape_string($runrows ['blog']);
        ?>
<div> 
<?php   
echo  $title."<br/>";
echo $body;
?></div>
     <?php
    }
    } 
    }
    }
     }
    ?>
```

Here is my db-controller and i saved it in a different folder **_inc/dbcontroller.php**

```
<?php
class DBController {
//include('Define.php');
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password = "12345";
    private $database = "ServerDBsclab";

    function __construct() {
        $db_conn = $this->connectDB();
        if(!empty($db_conn)) {
            $this->selectDB($db_conn);
        }
    }

    function connectDB() {
        $db_conn = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
        return $db_conn;
    }

    function selectDB($db_conn) {
        mysql_select_db($this->database,$db_conn);
    }

    function runQuery($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }       
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }

    function numRows($query) {
        $result  = mysql_query($query);
        $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;   
    }

    function updateQuery($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    function insertQuery($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    function deleteQuery($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) {
            die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

}
$db_conn = null;

?>
```

Here is my php pdo that i tried to use but is not working please help me with this so it will work like the above code

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['postid'])){
    echo '<h5 style="color: #2f2f2f;">Search</h5><br/>';
    $matchpost = $blog_title;
    $button = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['postid']);
$q = $blog_title;
$search_output = "";
// Prepare statement
$db_conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
$db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$search = $db_conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `blogtd` WHERE `blog` LIKE ?");
$search->execute(array("%$q%"));

foreach($search as $s){
    $id = $s["BID"];
    $title = $s["blog"];
    $body = substr($s["body"], 0, 50);
    $search_output .= '<article>
      <header><a href="'.$id.'">
        <h5>'.$title.'</h5>
        </a></header>
      <p>'.$body.'...</p></article>';
  } 
  echo $search_output;

}
?>
```

Comment: *"can someone convert this Mysql to PDO for me or MYSQLI but i prefer PDO because i understand it more"* - Stack isn't a conversion service.

Comment: I know am just asking if someone can help me with php search using pdo please is very important this is my final year project @Fred-ii-

Comment: What you need to do is this: Don't mix different MySQL APIs. Once you've used the same one from connecting to querying, you will have success.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i don't understand what you mean by (Don't mix different MySQL APIs. Once you've used the same one from connecting to querying, you will have success) please i will appreciate if you give me explanatory code for it, if necessary

Comment: `mysql_` + PDO = No love. `mysqli_` + PDO = No love. `mysql_` + `mysqli_` = No love ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its wat everyone is saying. Keep everything by 1 extension. If u use PDO, do everything in PDO. If u use mysqli. Do everything in mysqli. Never use mysql. (we live in 2016 now).

I'm only looking at your PDO code. It seems your missing some code how do you want to get your mysql data. Your don't fetch anything. I created a similar script for you that works a little different. Including my PDO class. Test it in your own server and check it that is working.

_inc/dbcontroller.php

```
<?php
class DBController{

    private $conn;
    public $error;

    private $stmt;

    public function __construct(){
        $driver = 'mysql';
        $host = 'localhost';
        $port = 3306;
        $user = 'user';
        $pass = 'pass';
        $db = 'mydb';
        $dsn = $driver.':host='.$host.';port='.$port.';dbname='.$db;
        // Set options
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );
        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }


    public function error(){
        return $this->stmt->errorInfo();
    }

    public function errorInfo(){
        return $this->stmt->errorInfo();
    }

    public function prepare($query){
        $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    }

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
        if(is_null($type)){
            switch(true){
                case is_int($value): $type = PDO::PARAM_INT; break;
                case is_bool($value): $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL; break;
                case is_null($value): $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL; break;
                default: $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute(){
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function rowCount(){
        return $this->stmt->rowCount();
    }

    public function getOne(){
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    public function getAll(){
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    public function getAllObject(){
        $result = new stdClass;
        $count = 0;
        while($row = $this->stmt->fetchObject()){
            $count++;
            $result->$count = $row;
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function getLastInsertId(){
        return $this->conn->lastInsertId();
    }

    public function free(){
        $this->stmt = null;
    }
}
```

Your call file

```
<?php


$search = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'q');
$output;

if(!empty($search)){
    require_once("_inc/dbcontroller.php");
    $db_handle = new DBController();
    $db_handle->prepare('SELECT * FROM blogtd WHERE blog LIKE :search');
    $db_handle->bind(':search', '%'.$search.'%');
    $db_handle->execute();
    $output = $db_handle->getAll(); // This is the thing i'm missing in your script.
    $db_handle->free();
}

if(!is_null($output)):
    $html = '';
    foreach($output as $i => $row){
        $id = $row->BID;
        $title = $row->blog;
        $body = substr($row->body, 0, 50);
        $html .= '
            <article>
                <header>
                    <a href="'.$id.'"><h5>'.$title.'</h5></a>
                </header>
                <p>'.$body.'</p>
            </article>';
    }
    echo $html;
else: ?>
<form id='searchform' method="GET" target="#">
    <input type='text' name='q' value=''/>
    <input type='submit' value='search'/>
</form><?php
endif;
```

Comment: should i replace my DBcontroller with this current one?

Comment: You can use everything in one file for testing. The pdo class replaces your DBcontroller yes.

Comment: I use it and is working very fine, so how can i go about using in in all page? `<?php require_once("_inc/dbcontroller.php"); $db_handle = new dbo();?>` and did i need this at the top of my page to replace this `<?php require_once("_inc/dbcontroller.php"); $db_handle = new DBController();?>`

Comment: Did edit my answer to how to fit in your code. Hope that is what you need.

Comment: I just replace my DB-controller with your own, but i gave so many errors in my previous code, if you can help fix it i will appreciate

Comment: Okey but it's to much for here. contact me on skype see my profile